# Sound not being played

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Phone.wav"))
sound.play(0, 20);
```

Why does sound not play? There are no errors.

Comment: Try to use a mp3 file, this link could be useful: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d25.html)

Comment: You need to use a SoundChannel try the docs

Answer (score 1):

Flash doesn't support loading external WAV files with the `Sound` class, only MP3s. I don't know why it isn't giving any errors but I haven't used the `Sound` class much myself so it might be normal.

There are three solutions for this. First of all, WAVs are supported if you import them into the library as `Sound` objects. This is probably the best choice if you're using the Flash IDE.
If you're not using the IDE, you may be able to embed the file instead using Flex's [Embed] tag, if you're compiling it using the Flex SDK.

Otherwise, can either convert your sound to an MP3 file and load it as usual:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Phone.mp3"));
sound.play(0, 20);
```

Or, if you prefer to use a WAV, you can use the [as3wavsound](http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/) library. [Here's a tutorial outlining how to use it.](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/media/quick-tip-play-external-wav-files-in-as3/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `SoundChannel` try this.

```
var soundChann:SoundChannel;
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Phone.wav"))
soundChann = sound.play();
```